# UIWebView strange behavior with cache policy

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlrequestcachepolicy

I'm having this problem with `UIWebView`:

Customer asked to check the cache policy of our `UIWebView` because, according to him, content updated on the server didn't appear on the device when reloading a page.

Now, I saw that the `NSURLRequest` that we're passing to the `UIWebView` has a `cachePolicy` of `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad`, which could enforce the customer thesis. If I understand this correctly, only the first request is loaded from the server, subsequent requests are loaded from the cache.

Then I changed the cachePolicy to `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy`, since I saw in the `NSURLRequest.h` headers that the interesting `NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData` is "unimplemented".

Everything seemed work well, until I did a rollback to the previous policy and I saw on Charles that everytime the `UIWebView` disappeared and then reappeared on the screen, a new request was done on the server, and mocking simple changes to the resulting page I could also see changes on the device.

Header returned by the server are btw:

```
Date    Tue, 13 Aug 2013 09:46:46 GMT
Content-Encoding    gzip
Server  Apache
ETag    "791e833a504a3a0f11fc74605ea244d2"
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control   public, max-age=60
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Content-Length  2685
Expires Tue, 13 Aug 2013 09:47:46 GMT
```

For a request done on the 13th of August at 11:46 GMT+2 (Berlin)

So to me the headers look fine, but still the `UIWebView` tries everytime to reload the contents.

I also took a look in the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` delegate method and I saw that the `cachePolicy` of the `request` was always set to 1 (`NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`).

How is this possible? And also how is then possible that the customer complained about the problem (he even sent me a screenshot, so this is not invented)

Thank you for your help

Comment: I got the same problem. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes, eventually I manually made the NSURLRequest using a NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy and started a NSURLConnection with that. Then, I loaded the HTML string when the connection finished loading.

Comment: so you didn't load the page with UIWebView's loadRequest: function but did it manually and then loaded the HTML into the UIWebView?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: Thanks. You could answer your own question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I manually made the `NSURLRequest` using a `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` and started a `NSURLConnection` with that. Then, I loaded the HTML string when the connection finished loading.